# How can I configure system properties or logback configuration variables from typesafe config?

Tags: scala, configuration, akka, logback, typesafe-stack

I have variables with defaults in my `logback.xml` configuration file, and I would like to be able to optionally set these variables from my typesafe config `application.conf` file.

I am deploying the application using one-jar, and the `application.conf` file packaged up in the deployable jar contains defaults.  I pass `-Dconfig.file=foo.conf` on execution to provide the path to a server-specific config file.

Right now I can also pass `-Dlog.level` and other variables to override my defaults in `logback.xml`, and I also have to pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on the command line.  I'm looking for a way to be able to specify these properties in the typesafe config instead of on the command line.  It feels like there should be a way to do it, but I can't find the magic words.

**logback.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.path:-logs/}/${log.file:-myLog.log}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 15 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>${log.history.days:-15}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="${log.level:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**application.conf (bundled):**

```
akka {
    log-config-on-start = false
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
}
```

**sample server-specific app.conf:**

```
include "/application.conf"

akka.log-config-on-start = true

log.level = WARN // this is what I'd LIKE to be able to do
```

**How I'm currently running the app:**

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dconfig.file=myApp.conf -Dlog.level=WARN -jar myApp_2.10-0.1-one-jar.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

I chose to programmatically configure logback having typesafe config. It turned out to be easy.

```
def enableRemoteLogging(config: Config) = {
    val ctx = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory.asInstanceOf[LoggerContext]

    val gelf = new GelfAppender
    gelf.setGraylog2ServerHost(config.getString("logging.remote.server"))
    gelf.setUseLoggerName(true)
    gelf.setUseThreadName(true)
    gelf.setUseMarker(true)
    gelf.setIncludeFullMDC(true)
    gelf.setContext(ctx)
    gelf.start()

    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
      .asInstanceOf[ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger]
      .addAppender(gelf)
  }
```

Comment: What is GelfAppender?

Comment: @AlekseiEgorov, it is the [Logback Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) implementation for sending [GELF](http://graylog2.org/gelf) to logging server like Graylog2 or Logstash. see [logback-gelf](https://github.com/Moocar/logback-gelf) project for details

Comment: This is the only one working (for me) example I've found on whole network! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `PropertyDefiner` interface that [logback provides](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly). Non trivial scaffolding but allows you to configure using XML instead of within your application. E.g.:

```java
package com.myapp;

import ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class TypesafeConfigPropertyDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {

    private String propertyName;

    @Override
    public String getPropertyValue() {
        return ConfigFactory.load().getString( propertyName );
    }

    public void setPropertyName( String propertyName ) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Then, in your logback.xml file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <define name="loglevel" class="com.myapp.TypesafeConfigPropertyDefiner">
        <propertyName>myapp.logging.loglevel</propertyName>
    </define>
    <root level="${loglevel}">
       ...
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Now, the above logback.xml file will read `myapp.logging.loglevel` from your typesafe config file (e.g. `application.conf`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Logback, but a normal Akka application ships with default settings in its `reference.conf`, and you override these settings in an `application.conf`. It sounds like you want to add a *third* layer of configuration, which is certainly your right!

The easiest way I can see is to change your `application.conf` to include your `foo.conf` rather than the other way around. That way Akka will load the `application.conf`, which will then load `foo.conf`.

But that may not work if you need a differently-named conf file for each JAR distribution. In which case I recommend you look into [Merging Config Trees](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#merging-config-trees) to programmatically load and combine configuration. Actually, [Reading configuration from a custom location](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/configuration.html#Reading_configuration_from_a_custom_location)  in the Akka Configuration docs is almost exactly what you want, except you will want to load `myConfig` from a classpath resource rather than by parsing a string (see the Typesafe Config docs to find out how to do that).

Regarding the Logback configuration, like I said, I don't know Logback. But you can read values out an Typesafe configuration [like so](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#api-example), and you can set the Logback root logger level [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838108/49630).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have a pretty good handle on the cascading configuration options; what I'm unclear about is how to use typesafe config to set system properties, i.e. variables that I otherwise have to pass in using `-Dsome.variable=value`.  I think if I can get over that hurdle for, say, `-Dfile.encoding`, it is likely to work for all the logback variable bindings.

Comment: That's easy: just read the value out of the Typesafe Config file and then call `System.setProperty()`. But it might not work if the properties have already been read. System properties are usually best set on the command line. For runtime configuration it's better to use each framework's standard configuration approach.