# Using application.conf values to configure logger.xml

Tags: playframework-2.0, logback

I am using the SMTPAppender to send error logs to an email address. I was wondering is there a way to set the username and password through the application.conf instead of hard coding it in the logger.xml?

For example in the application.conf have the following

email.username="my-username"
email.password="my-password"

and in the logger.xml:

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>587</smtpPort>
    <STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
    <username>{email.username}</username>
    <password>{email.password}</password>
    <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>
    <to>admin@my.com</to>
    <from>me@my.com</from>
    <subject>SERVER ERROR: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
     <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
   </layout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097967/how-can-i-configure-system-properties-or-logback-configuration-variables-from-ty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I configure system properties or logback configuration variables from typesafe config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097967/how-can-i-configure-system-properties-or-logback-configuration-variables-from-ty)