# Google secret manager

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform

I have just included Google secret manager

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

in one of our maven projects. When i tried to use these APIs it is throwing below error

[DEBUG] [http-apr-8080-exec-68] [io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader] - i.g.n.s.i.n.u.i.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary:344 : Unable to load the library 'io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-05-19T10:44:47.728098547Z”}

Does anyone know what is this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have other dependencies? Can you share more of your pom.xml file?

Comment: Sharing related Stackdriver case " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837801/how-to-change-root-logging-level-programmatically-for-logback " which might assist with some recommendations to overcome your issue

Answer (score 0):

When I updated java version on environment, it got solved.

Thanks for everyone.